# Unable to insert ListView via the REST API

Tags: rest-api, metadata

When I try to insert the ListView object using the REST API I get the following error:

`[{"message":"entity type cannot be inserted: List View","errorCode":"CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY","fields":[]}]`

Is there a permission I am missing, or is this even possible?

---

Endpoint: `<Instanceurl>/services/data/v35.0/sobjects/ListView/`

Simplified JSON, but same error: `{"Name":"This is a test"}`

Comment: You've tagged this question as both metadata-api and rest-api. Which is it? Can you show us the URL you're posting to, and the payload?

Comment: This is for the REST API, sorry about that, I have removed the `metadata-api` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ListView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_listview.htm), in the SOAP and REST API, only supports the following actions:

> describeSObjects(), query(), retrieve()

In other words, these two APIs are read-only.

You need to use the [ListView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listview.htm) found in the Metadata API in order to create, update, or delete list views. Instead of having to build a package.xml, zipping up everything, and so on, you can also use the [createMetadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_createMetadata.htm) Metadata call to submit a handful of ListView objects at a time.